# When using mectrics in model.compile in keras, report ValueError: ('Unknown metric function', ':f1score')

Tags: keras, metrics

I'm trying to run a LSTM, and when I use the code below:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', 'f1score', 'precision', 'recall'])
```

It returns:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown metric function', ':f1score').
```

I've done my searches and found this url:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5400

The "metrics" in the "model.compile" part in this url is exactly the same as mine, and no errors are returned.

Comment: What's your Keras version (you can check with `keras.__version__`)?  
f1score is not available in Keras 2 and you need to create it yourself (a good start to do that would be to look at the 1.2.2 code : https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/1.2.2/keras/metrics.py)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect you are using Keras 2.X.  As explained in https://keras.io/metrics/, you can create custom metrics.  These metrics appear to take only `(y_true, y_pred)` as function arguments, so a generalized implementation of fbeta is not possible.

Here is an implementation of `f1_score` based on the keras 1.2.2 source code.

```py
import keras.backend as K

def f1_score(y_true, y_pred):
  
    # Count positive samples.
    c1 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    c2 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    c3 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))

    # If there are no true samples, fix the F1 score at 0.
    if c3 == 0:
        return 0.0

    # How many selected items are relevant?
    precision = c1 / (c2 + K.epsilon())

    # How many relevant items are selected?
    recall = c1 / (c3 + K.epsilon())

    # Calculate f1_score
    f1_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    return f1_score
```

To use, simply add `f1_score` to your list of metrics when you compile your model, after defining the custom metric.  For example:

```py
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy',f1_score])
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have added your code into my project, but the output of f1_score is always nan, I don't know how to deal it, can you help me?

Comment: `model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy', metric_def.f1_score])`

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Check to see if you are dividing by zero in the calculation of precision, recall or f1_score.

Comment: But the result of each line is NaN, and the accuracy and loss function are all value, the accuracy rate is higher than the positive and negative sample ratio, so we think should not be divided by zero problem. Is there any other possibility of causing this problem ? @dhinckley

Comment: After the model is compiled and prediction done, how can the `f1_score` be printed out?

Comment: `f1_score` is reported using `model.evaluate(..)`.  The name of each reported value can be seen with `print(model.metrics_names)`

Comment: adding some epsilons for a division is essential - `K.epsilon()`

Comment: For anyone that gets an error: `TypeError: 'retval_' has dtype int32 in the main branch, but dtype float32 in the else branch` using the above function, change `return 0` to `return 0.0`. It is a datatype issue, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68040877/10374379 @dhinckley can you please update answer?

Answer (score 0):

K.epsilon() works well in this code. You can use this in the definition of c1, c2, and c3.