# ValueError: Unknown metric function: precision

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I've tried to implementing my training model into a flask web app, when I try to input this code

```
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)
total_loss = sm.losses.JaccardLoss()
metrics = [sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.Precision(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.Recall(threshold=0.5)]

link_model = 'models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_50_256_yes.h5'
model = keras.models.load_model(link_model, custom_objects={'jaccard_loss': total_loss, 'iou_score':metrics[0], 'f1-score':metrics[1], 'precision_score':metrics[2], 'recall-score':metrics[3]})
model.compile(optim, total_loss, metrics)
model.load_weights('models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_50_256_yes_best_weights.h5')
print('success load model')
model.make_predict_function()
```

it seems to show errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 52, in <module>
    model = keras.models.load_model(link_model, custom_objects={'jaccard_loss': total_loss, 'iou_score':metrics[0], 'f1-score':metrics[1], 'precision-score':metrics[2], 'recall-score':metrics[3]})
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 182, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 193, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model.compile(**saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 223, in compile_args_from_training_config
    metrics = _deserialize_nested_config(_deserialize_metric, metrics_config)
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 265, in _deserialize_nested_config
    return [_deserialize_nested_config(deserialize_fn, obj) for obj in config]
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 265, in <listcomp>
    return [_deserialize_nested_config(deserialize_fn, obj) for obj in config]
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 258, in _deserialize_nested_config
    return deserialize_fn(config)
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 288, in _deserialize_metric
    return metrics_module.deserialize(metric_config)
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 3439, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\DIS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 377, in deserialize_keras_object
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown metric function: precision
```

when I tried different model training it doesn't show an error like that, did I mistake it in my code so it can't work on a different model? I try some from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345909/when-using-mectrics-in-model-compile-in-keras-report-valueerror-unknown-metr) but it doesn't help my problem.

the reason I use `custom_object` is I take some line code from my training code which is like this:

```
model = keras.models.load_model(save_dir[0]+model_path+'/'+model_path+'.h5', custom_objects={'jaccard_loss': total_loss, 'iou_score':metrics[0], 'f1-score':metrics[1], 'precision_score':metrics[2], 'recall_score':metrics[3]})
```

and when I use it for implementing it shows an error on above.

Comment: i thought i solve my problem by change `custom_object` into `compile=false`. because I ran another model and use 2 of them, the web app can work/run.

Comment: and when use 2 of them, `custom_object` and `compile=false` show same error I think it's clear

Answer (score 0):

As per the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision), the argument name is `thresholds` against `threshold` (notice 's') and it is a `list`.

Comment: I use the same code for 2 models, but the other model can run it with different metrics like f1 and IoU. so I think I `threshold` is not the problem, I also run the same code `threshold` on my training code.

Comment: did you try changing it to `sm.metrics.Precision(threshold=[0.5])`?

Comment: not yet, BTW this is the `metrics = [sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5)]` metrics on my other models.

Comment: that is not call to `metrics.Precision` function.

Comment: so what I must use then? coz I just confuse when my training can use it but this one cant. Or I must change it to `metrics.PrecisionScore`?

Comment: if you want to use `sm.metrics.Precision` call should be `sm.metrics.Precision(thresholds=[0.5]`. If you want to use the two you are already using then it should be as you used them. Give it a try and see if that works or you get different error update the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234496/discussion-between-vish-and-uzrsa).

Comment: ok, i've sent in disscussion and it seems show same error